# How get capacity of network in Amazon AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I want to get Maximum Capacity for network interfaces in Amazon EC2 Instance?

when I used this command:
$ sudo lshw -class network

the result is:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 0e:bf:3b:c5:cd:20
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vif ip=10.0.1.14 link=yes multicast=yes
```

but I need `capacity` that [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/586322/how-to-find-out-capacity-for-network-interfaces) you can see as a result.

could someone help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It's a virtualized network card in EC2, so there isn't a capability value available.

There's a table [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html) that shows the network bandwidth available to many of the instance types.  For types not documented, you can start up two identical machines in the same placement group, and use `iperf` to measure it, rounding up to the nearest sensible value.

Comment: the table is just for Premium Instances.